# Feature selection - Before vs After oversampling

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, random-forest, feature-selection

I understand that class imbalance is not considered as a problem by some of experts here. But for the sake of experimentation, I would like to try out the oversampling for my data (which is of 77:23 proportion).

I am working on a binary classification problem using traditional ML algos (e.g., random forest) and neural networks.

As most of my variables are categorical and highly cardinal in nature, I use encoding methods like `ordinal_encoder`, `rare_encoder` etc.

So, my question is

a) Should I select the best features first and then oversample my data using SMOTE? or I have to upsample first and then do the feature selection?

can you also let me know the reason as to why it should be done the way you suggest (and not the other way round)?

Comment: What are the goals of the project, and how do you asses whether you've achieved them? What is the purpose of oversampling? Of SMOTE? Of feature selection?

Comment: Just to clarify something, the statement "*class imbalance is not considered as a problem by the users here*" is a bit of an over-generalisation. If class imbalance means that we have an inadequate number of training examples, it is absolutely a problem. If anything, the question is why you want to oversample. (And a 77:23 split is pretty OK... most "imbalanced" applications are considered with the minority classs to be in the single digits proportion-wise)

Comment: @Sycorax - Am just trying to know which is the right way to do feature selection - Should I do before over sampling or after over sampling? My project goal is binary classification focused on better performance for minority class. I am already using the f1-score but it is only around 58%. I exhausted feature engineerimg ideas that I could think of. So, wanted to see whether doing feature selection before or after makes a difference.

Comment: While I may do it both before and after and assess the performance of the model, but which is the right way? Or is there even a right way to do it?

Comment: @usεr11852 - I agree with your point on class imbalance. Meanimg, my data is not heavily imbalanced. But I dont know what more I can do to improve the performance of my model. I tried feature engineerimg, feature selection using multiple methods etc. But yes, my dataset has only 977 records. So, having nothing more to try, I thought finally I will try oversampling. And when I oversample, I want to make sure that I am doing the feature selection right

Comment: @usεr11852 - updated the post to remove overgenralization